# Keep New JavaScript Values for Active Session/Apply JavaScript Styling to All Pages During Active Session

Tags: javascript, html, css, session

For a project I am making some functions to try and improve user experience. One function I use takes in a number value and set the font size in paragraphs to that value. If the user moves to a different page, the size goes back to the CSS value I put in my styles sheet. Is there a way to carry over the input value and apply it to the CSS for that session?

```
function changeFS(id){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById(id);
    var pArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (var i = 0; i < pArray.length; i++) {
        pArray[i].style.fontSize = inputValue.value + "pt";
    }
    inputValue.value="";
}
```

Comment: pls find the similar discussion, might be helpful to you http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105524/is-it-realistic-to-make-use-of-html5-local-storage-to-store-css-and-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is utilize localStorage.  The MDN has an excellent reference at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage.

Essentially you'll be able to:

```
localStorage.setItem('fontSize', '15px');
localStorage.getItem('fontSize');
```

You can see a compatibility chart at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
and an imitation over cookies at the first link